# compare hours of the day with moments.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a day planner app and I am using moments.js. I have an array of objects and each object has the hours and a blank activity.

I am trying to display each hour/activity to the page which is working but I am also trying to compare the hours listed to the current hour and set the style to past/present/future depending on if the hour is before, after, or equal to the current hour. I'm trying to use isBefore and isAfter but it isn't working.

Everything is working except I cannot find a way to determine if 10 am is before or after 11 am for example.

Here is my code.  It will go from 8 am - 5 pm but I added extra objects as it's late now.

```
let mySched = [
    {
        hour:  '8 am',
        activity: ''
    },
    {
        hour: '9 am',
        activity: ''
    },
    {
        hour: '10 am',
        activity: ''
    },
    {
        hour: '11 am',
        activity: ''
    },
    {
        hour: '12 am',
        activity: ''
    },
    {
        hour: '1 pm',
        activity: ''
    },
    {
        hour: '2 pm',
        activity: ''
    },
    {
        hour: '3 pm',
        activity: ''
    },
    {
        hour: '4 pm',
        activity: ''
    },
    {
        hour: '5 pm',
        activity: ''
    },
    {
        hour: '06 pm',
        activity: ''
    },
    {
        hour: '07 pm',
        activity: ''
    },
    {
        hour: '08 pm',
        activity: ''
    },
    {
        hour: '09 pm',
        activity: ''
    },
    {
        hour: '10 pm',
        activity: ''
    },
    {
        hour: '11 pm',
        activity: ''
    },
    {
        hour: '12 pm',
        activity: ''
    }
]

function whenIsNow(hour) {
    if (moment().isAfter(hour)) {
        return 'future';
    } else if (moment().isBefore(hour)) {
        return 'past';
    } else  {
        return 'present';
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i < mySched.length; i++) {
    let myHour = mySched[i].hour;
    let timeBlock = $(
        `<div class="col-12 time-block">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="${i}" class="col-12 col-md-2 hour">${myHour}</div>
                    <div id="description" class="col-12 col-md-8 description ${whenIsNow(myHour)}"><textarea name="description">test</textarea></div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-2 button"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`
    )
    let schedTime = $(`#${i}`);
    schedTime.append(myHour);
    plannerEl.append(timeBlock);
}
```

Comment: Off topic: note that you should only prefix hours with `0` when using 24 hour time - eg 08 = 8am, an normally as "military" time, eg "0800 hours".  "06" is always "6 am",  you can't (shouldn't) have "06 pm" - that's just "6pm".  (but likely just that way as you added them when it's late in the day)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing.

```
// get the current day
let myDay = moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY");
// target current day div
let currentDayEl = $('#currentDay');
// Append the date to current day div
currentDayEl.append(myDay);
// target the container
let containerEl = $('.container');
let mySched = [];

// get the current hour
let currHour = (moment().get('hour'));

// function to check if the the 
//current hour is before, after, or the same as 
// each hour of the planner and setting the 
// past, present, or future class to the event
function whenIsNow(hour) {
    // this is the hour passed to the function
    let myHour = (moment(parseInt(hour)));
    // compare the hour passed in to the current hour
    // and set the class acordingly
    if (myHour.isSame(currHour)) {
        return 'present';
    } else if (myHour.isBefore(currHour)) {
        return 'past';
    } else  if (myHour.isAfter(currHour)) {
        return 'future';
    }
}

// function to convert hour displayed to 12 hour time 
// and add am or pm.
function convertTime(myHour) {
    if (myHour > 0 && myHour <= 12) {
        myHour = myHour + 'am';
      } else if (myHour > 12) {
        (myHour = myHour - 12 + 'pm');
      } else if (myHour == 0) {
        myHour = 12 + 'am';
      }
      return myHour;
}

// count from 9-18 and create each time block
for (let i = 9; i < 18; i++) {
    // get event[i] from local storage
    let currentEvent = localStorage.getItem(i);
    // if the current event is null set currentEvent to ''
    if (currentEvent == null) {
        currentEvent = '';
    }
    
    // create the timeBlocks
    let timeBlock = $(
        `<div class="row">
            <div id="${i}" class="col-1 d-flex justify-content-center hour">${convertTime(i)}</div>
            <div id="description" class="col-9 description ${whenIsNow(i)}"><textarea class="myText">${currentEvent}</textarea></div>
            <div class="col-2 pl-0"><button class="btn btn-lg saveBtn"><i class="far fa-save"></i></button></div>
        </div>`
    );
    // append time blocks to container element
    containerEl.append(timeBlock);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I STRONGLY suggest not to store the time in string format and use 24hour format for coding. Then convert the displayed value to ampm

```js
let mySched = [ "Activity at midnight", "Activity at 1am", "Activity at 2am", "Activity at 3am", "Activity at 4am", "Activity at 5am", "Activity at 6am", "Activity at 7am", "Activity at 8am", "Activity at 9am", "Activity at 10am", "Activity at 11am", "Activity at 12am", "Activity at 1pm", "Activity at 2pm", "Activity at 3pm", "Activity at 4pm", "Activity at 5pm", "Activity at 6pm", "Activity at 7pm", "Activity at 8pm", "Activity at 9pm", "Activity at 10pm", "Activity at 11pm" ];

const nowHour = new Date().getHours()
const ampm = num => num > 12 ? `${num-12}pm` : `${num}am`
const whenTime = (hour,when) => { if (hour < when) return "past"; if (hour === when) return "now"; return "future" };
$("#planner").html(mySched.map((shed,i) => `<div class="col-12 time-block">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="${ampm(i)}" class="col-12 col-md-2 hour">${i === 0? 'midnight' : ampm(i)}</div>
                    <div id="description" class="col-12 col-md-8">${whenTime(i,nowHour)} <textarea name="description">${shed}</textarea></div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-2 button"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`).join("")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="planner"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm doing this in a class and I have to use moments.js. I can display the current time and day and can even get the current hour but I can't compare it to what is in the array even if I save it as a number.

Comment: `I'm doing this in a class and I have to use moments.js`  - seems you need to use specific strings https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/03-is-after/ and "1 am" might not be one that works - you can try `moment().format("h A");`

Comment: *I have to use moments.js* - are you sure?  Even the developers of [tag:moment] suggest you don't use moment!   In this case it's a *very* simply string parse instead of the *huge* overhead of moment.   Check for "pm" in the string then add twelve to the parsed number - then simple comparison with two numbers (the other extracted from `(new Date).getHours()`)